# How to manage checkbox filtering with React?

Tags: forms, reactjs, checkbox

I am working on my first React app. It is a recipe sort of app. It has an ingredients filter. The main component is the Cookbook component. It has a Filter component and a Recipe component.

The Recipe component displays all recipes on load. The Filter component displays all needed ingredients or staples. This part all works great.

What I want to do now is when a person clicks on a staple, lets say butter, it would then filter the entire recipe list. My assumption is that I need to pass the state of Filter up. How can I do this with these checkboxes?

Here is what I have:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
var data = require('./recipes.json');

function IngredientDetailList(props){
    const ingredientList = props.ingredientList;
    const listItems = ingredientList.map((ingredient, index) => 
        <div key={index}> 
            {ingredient.measurement_amount}&nbsp;
            {ingredient.measurement_unit}&nbsp;
            {ingredient.ingredient}
        </div>

    );
    return (
        <div>{listItems}</div>
    )
}


function Recipe(props){
    const recipeList = props.cookbook.recipes
    const listItems = recipeList.map((recipe) =>
        <div key={recipe.id}>
            <h2>{recipe.name}</h2>
            <IngredientDetailList ingredientList = {recipe.ingredient_list}/>
        </div>

    );
    return(

        <div>{listItems}</div>
    )
}

class Filter extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            checkedStaples: {},
        }
    }

    render(){
        const stapleList = this.props.stapleList;
        const checkboxItems = stapleList.map((staple, index) => 
            <div key = {index}>
            <label>
                <input type="checkbox" value="{staple}"/>
                {staple}
            </label>
            </div>
        );
        return (
            <form>
                {checkboxItems}
            </form>
        );
    }
}


class Cookbook extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super(); 
        this.state ={
            cookbook: data
        }   
    }

    getStapleList(recipes){
        let stapleList = [];
        recipes.forEach(function(recipe){
            recipe.ingredient_list.forEach(function(list){
                stapleList.push(list.needed_staple);
            });
        });

        let flattenedStapleList = stapleList.reduce(function(a,b){
            return a.concat(b);
        })

        return flattenedStapleList
    }

    render(){
        const cookbook = this.state.cookbook;
        const stapleList = this.getStapleList(cookbook.recipes);
        return(
            <div className="cookbook">
                <div className="filter-section">
                    <h1>This is the filter section</h1>
                    <Filter stapleList = {stapleList}/>
                </div>
                <div className="recipes">
                    <h1>This is where the recipes go</h1>
                    <div className="recipe">    
                        <Recipe cookbook = {cookbook}/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Cookbook />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try to do something like this:

```
// ....

function Recipe(props){
    const selectedStaples = props.selectedStaples;
    const recipeList = props.cookbook.recipes

    const listItems = recipeList.map((recipe) => {
        const hasStaple = ingredient_list.reduce(
            (_hasStaple, staple) => _hasStaple || selectedStaples.includes(staple),
            false
        );

        // only show recipe if it has a staple
        if (selectedStaples.length === 0 || hasStaple)
            return (
                <div key={recipe.id}>
                    <h2>{recipe.name}</h2>
                    <IngredientDetailList ingredientList = {recipe.ingredient_list}/>
                </div>
            );
        }

        return null;
    }

    );
    return(

        <div>{listItems}</div>
    )
}

class Filter extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super();
        this.state = {
            checkedStaples: {},
        }
    }

    render(){
        const stapleList = this.props.stapleList;
        const checkboxItems = stapleList.map((staple, index) => 
            <div key = {index}>
            <label>
                <input
                    type="checkbox"
                    value="{staple}"
                    onClick={e => this.props.onChange(staple, e.checked)}
                />
                {staple}
            </label>
            </div>
        );
        return (
            <form>
                {checkboxItems}
            </form>
        );
    }
}


class Cookbook extends React.Component {
    constructor(){
        super(); 
        this.state ={
            cookbook: data,
            selectedStaples: []
        }   
    }

    getStapleList(recipes){
        let stapleList = [];
        recipes.forEach(function(recipe){
            recipe.ingredient_list.forEach(function(list){
                stapleList.push(list.needed_staple);
            });
        });

        let flattenedStapleList = stapleList.reduce(function(a,b){
            return a.concat(b);
        })

        return flattenedStapleList
    }

    handleOnChange(staple, isChecked) {
        const selectedStaples = this.state.selectedStaples;
        if (isChecked) {
            this.setState({
                selectedStaples: selectedStaples.push(staple);
            })
        } else {
            this.setState({
                selectedStaples: selectedStaples.filter(selectedStaple => selectedStaple !== staple);
            })
        }
    }

    render(){
        const selectedStaples = this.state.selectedStaples;
        const cookbook = this.state.cookbook;
        const stapleList = this.getStapleList(cookbook.recipes);
        return(
            <div className="cookbook">
                <div className="filter-section">
                    <h1>This is the filter section</h1>
                    <Filter stapleList = {stapleList} onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}/>
                </div>
                <div className="recipes">
                    <h1>This is where the recipes go</h1>
                    <div className="recipe">    
                        <Recipe cookbook = {cookbook} selectedStaples={selectedStaples} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Cookbook />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

It keeps track of the selected stapes in the cookbook component and passes that on to  recipe

Comment: So, I added this and tweaked it to make it work. Thanks for the help! One issue I am seeing is that I cannot seem to make handleOnChange work... specifically, this.state.selectedStaples keeps on bombing out as undefined. My current guess is that it doesn't see that parameter within the context of Filter, for which I tried to pass down the state as well... still no luck. I am going to add my update to the edit... any idea?

Comment: Ah yea, the reason is because you're using a es6 class for a component, the method is not automatically bound to `this`. You can change `onChange={this.handleOnChange}` to `onChange={() => this.handleOnChange()}` or `onChange={this.handleOnChange.bind(this)}`